# Multi-dimension dictionary in configparser

Tags: python, dictionary, configparser

Is it possible to store a multi-dimensional dictionary (3 deep) using the Python 'configparser' using indentions?  The work-around is to split the key values, but wanted to know if there was a clean way to import directly into a dictionary.

**DOES NOT WORK - USING SUB-OPTION INDENTION IN CONFIGPARSER**

```
    [OPTIONS]
        [SUB-OPTION]
        option1 = value1
        option2 = value2
        option3 = value3
```

**WORKS - SPLITING USED ON SUB-OPTION VALUES**

```
    [OPTIONS]
    SUB-OPTION  = 'option1, value1',    
                  'option2, value2',
                  'option3, value3'
```

**DICTIONARY VALUES**

```
    dict['OPTIONS']['SUB-OPTION'] = {
        option1 : value1,
        option2 : value2,
        option3 : value3,
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASAIK, there is a nested configuration file in that format.

I suggest a json like config file:

```
{
 "OPTIONS": {
   "SUB-OPTIONS": {
     "option1" : value1,
     "option2" : value2,
     "option3" : value3,
   }
 }
}
```

Then in the code use:

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open("filename","r") as f:
 config = literal_eval(f.read())
```

## Edit

Alternatively, you can use YAML (with PyYAML) as a great configuration file.

The following configuration file:

```yaml
option1:
    suboption1:
        value1: hello
        value2: world
    suboption2:
        value1: foo
        value2: bar
```

Can be parsed using:

```
import yaml
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    conf = yaml.safe_load(f)
```

Then you can access the data as you would in a `dict`:

```
conf['option1']['suboption1']['value1']
>> 'hello'
```

Comment: Thanks, was trying to have a more human readable configuration file with the built-in Python configparser, but looks like JSON is the only built-in solution.  YAML may be another option.

Comment: Then I'm guessing that the easiest way arround it is just using the following format:
[OPTION,SUBOPTION]
option1=value1
option2=value2
option3=value3

Then parse it using configparse it and splitting every category name according to commas and buid the dictionery as you mentioned.

Comment: YAML might also be wroth a look

Comment: I found a Python package [ConfigObj](http://configobj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configobj.html) that has nested sections, but the last time it was maintained was in 2014.

Answer (score 2):

config.ini

```
OPTIONS  = {"option1": "value1", "option2": "value2", "option3": "value3"}
```

Code:

```
import json
options = json.loads(conf['OPTIONS'])
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out: the requested nesting capability is not supported by the current `configparser` implementation.

However, `TOML` configuration files follow a similar syntax to `INI` files and allow for nested structures. See the official specification [here](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml) and the corresponding python library [here](https://github.com/uiri/toml).

You may also checkout [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998034/does-toml-support-nested-arrays-of-objects-tables) with the following example:

```
name = "A Test of the TOML Parser"

[[things]]
a = "thing1"
b = "fdsa"
multiLine = """
Some sample text."""

[[things]]
a = "Something else"
b = "zxcv"
multiLine = """
Multiline string"""
[[things.objs]]
x = 1
[[things.objs]]
x = 4
[[things.objs]]
x = 7
[[things.objs.morethings]]
y = [
    2,
    3,
    4
]
[[things.objs.morethings]]
y = 9

[[things]]
a = "3"
b = "asdf"
multiLine = """
thing 3.
another line"""
```

JSON output:

```
{
    "name": "A Test of the TOML Parser",
    "things": [{
        "a": "thing1",
        "b": "fdsa",
        "multiLine": "Some sample text."
    }, {
        "a": "Something else",
        "b": "zxcv",
        "multiLine": "Multiline string",
        "objs": [{
            "x": 1
        }, {
            "x": 4
        }, {
            "x": 7,
            "morethings": [{
                "y": [2, 3, 4]
            }, {
                "y": 9
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "a": "3",
        "b": "asdf",
        "multiLine": "thing 3.\\nanother line"
    }]
}
```